# Search and find in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search

I need help for writing a macro to use in Excel. Essentially what I'm working with is large groups of financial data that are almost always unique. I need to be able to compare each cell in one column (`B`) to another entire column (`H`) to search for a matching value. After finding the matching value, I need the macro to print the value related to the original found value into the cell next to the searched value. (Column `G` will have titles referring to the value of cell `H`)

Basically I need to be able to compare the individual value of each cell in column `B` to the entire column `H`, and if and when there is a match, have the value of column `G` appear in column `A` next to the original cell in column `B`. Sorry for the terrible explanation.

Search Column `H` for value match of `B2`. If `H30 = B30`, print `G30` in `A2`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, but if you have some code you are having trouble getting to work we would love to help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use `VLOOKUP()`, you'll need to use a nested `MATCH()` and `INDEX()`.

`=INDEX(G:G,MATCH(B1,H:H,FALSE))`

For reference:

- [INDEX()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- [MATCH()](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca)
- [Searching](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Look-up-values-with-VLOOKUP-INDEX-or-MATCH-68297403-7C3C-4150-9E3C-4D348188976B)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not need a macro for this.  Try the VLOOKUP function: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65

Edit:
Syntax should be something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, G:H, 2, FALSE)
```

then fill down and adjust absolute references as appropriate for your spreadsheet.

Comment: any suggestions on the syntax of the Vlookup? I've tried that already and I cant figure out how to return a value that was not the matched value itself.

Comment: @LukeSagaser I've edited the answer to add syntax.  Note that VLOOKUP always searches the first column of the array, and then returns values from that column or columns to the right - if you absolutely cannot reorder your columns, you will need to use a different function.